# CSS - Custom Fonts?

Tags: css, fonts

I have a design and Myriad Pro is required. This isn't a problem. The issue is that in Photoshop they have used 'Bold Condensed'. I am not sure what this is called, I think it is one of the varients of Myriad Pro. What is the best way to emulate this on a website?

Thanks.

Comment: Myriad Pro is not a web-safe font (Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, and Trebuchet are the main sans-serif web fonts), so how were you going to use it on your site in the first place? If you're going to embed a custom web font, then it doesn't matter what style it is. There's no emulation needed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) is your best resource. Their "@font-face generator" creates code that will work with all the modern browsers.

What they do is well-explained but behind the scenes it's pretty complicated. You can read up on the CSS aspects on [Paul Irish's blog](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/).

**Edit**

I just realized that *nobody* has answered your **real** question...

1.) `Myriad Pro` is a *family* of fonts, implemented as a collection of files, with names like `Myriad Pro.otf`, `Myriad Pro Bold.otf`, and so forth. (The actual names are OS-specific.) `Myriad Pro Bold Condensed` is one of those files. I don't know if it comes with the standard package or whether it costs extra.

2.) **You cannot "emulate" this.** You can either use the actual font on your webpage (via the @font-face embedding method described above), or create a graphic. The designers probably expect you to create graphics, because designers [tirade deleted] when it comes to implementation.

3.) As has been pointed out, embedding supposedly requires an appropriate license, and I don't know if you can get such a license for this particular face. ("Supposedly", because [tirade deleted], but I'm not a lawyer.)

Answer (score 1):

The 100% guaranteed way is to render it to an image.

CSS3 supports font-face but this will not give you wide support.

```
@font-face
{
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
  src: url('Myriad-Pro.ttf');
}
```

You will also need to check legal agreements to see if they allow embedding this font in your pages.

Comment: You're probably right. I am yet to try this one out... when it is widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try Shaun Inman's [sIFR3](http://novemberborn.net/sifr3), although CSS3 is likely to be the better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

However, see license first. In many cases you can not use @font-face.

Here is post on adobe about myriad license for web.
http://forums.adobe.com/message/3654436